# Which is fastest in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP String concatenation - “$a $b” vs $a . “ ” . $b - performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813673/php-string-concatenation-a-b-vs-a-b-performance)

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/';

    //case 1
    $case1 = 'The URL is '.$url.'.';

    //case 2
    $case2 = "The URL is $url.";

    //case 3
    $case3 = 'The URL is {url}.';
    $case3 = str_replace('{url}', $url, $case3);
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It would be nearly trivial to try and find out yourself.

Comment: *We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time:* ***premature optimization is the root of all evil***. *Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to* ***look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified”*** *- Donald Knuth*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case 1 and 2 are basically the same (don't worry about your 2 nanoseconds lost) – i think there are questions on SO covering this issue. case 3 is probably slower due to string search and replacement. if you really want to know, profile all three cases.

Comment: I was tested. Why I got the result is `Case 3 fastest > Case 1 adn Case 2`

Comment: @bravo: can you show your testcases? i don't think there's a flaw somewhere in them